# How can I export MBTiles from TileMill 2?

Tags: export, mapbox, mbtiles, vector-tiles, tilemill-2

In TileMill 1 it was easy to export MBTiles for a selected region with my own style. In TileMill 2 I can only package the style or export vector tiles from a previously imported datasource.

How can I export MBTiles with my custom style? Thanks for any hints. I haven’t been able to Google anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a [final word](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio/issues/373) from a developer regarding this matter.

Comment: However there is a way to [do it anyway](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2015/05/converting-mapbox-studio-vector-tiles-to-rasters/) using [tessera](https://github.com/mojodna/tessera).